# authorized uses only error in api call - devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I followed the [document](http://www.developingandrails.com/2015/02/api-authentication-with-devisetokenauth.html) here which is an abstract from official document and tried to make simple API calls, everything worked fine but none got through "authorized users only" error when making REST calls.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/?email=bala223344@gmail.com&password=object123&password_confirmation=object123
```

It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#token-header-format) that the headers should be sent, but i understand those are for subsquent requests

Answer (score 0):

ah found the answer finally, i checked the log and it said

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

and i went ahead and changed this ApplicationController

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```